# SiSense : Facing Issue while Installation

Tags: data-visualization

I am new to SiSense and was trying to install it to my system However, I am facing trouble with while the installation.

During installation, Its unable to start Sisense.Oxygen services due to insufficient privileges. Can someone help me to fix this
[image]

Comment: Hi,
From where did you get the sisense executable file ? 
I downloaded the one specified here : https://documentation.sisense.com/l2022-3-x/docs/release-notes-3
but it is not working
and the link mentioned on there community page is broken 
https://community.sisense.com/t5/knowledge/install-issues-stuck-on-quot-downloading-sisense-licensing/ta-p/883

Answer (score 0):

It looks  like the installation process didn't have sufficient privileges to start the system service. I'd suggest that you:

1. Right-click the installation file, and select Run as Administrator
2. Restart the machine

If this doesn't get the installation to work, I'd suggest that you reach out to Sisense's support team by emailing information about your problem to support@sisense.com.